# VBA Excel 2010 - Delete Rows without max value of column based in another column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've got an excel spreadsheet with several columns, two of them have an ID (that repeats itself) and a date.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to delete all rows by ID leaving only the row with the max date.

I have a second sheet with all the unique IM's.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
Public Sub sbMaxDateByIM()

Dim max As Date
Dim currentIM As String
Dim MaxDateCurrentIM As Date
Dim dateRange As Range
Dim imrange As Range

Application.Sheets("sheet1").Activate


Set dateRange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("E2"), ActiveSheet.Range("E2").End(xlDown))
Set imrange = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A2"), ActiveSheet.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Sheets("UniqueIMS").Activate

    For IM = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

           currentIM = Sheets("UniqueIMS").Cells(IM, 1).Value

            MaxDateCurrentIM = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(""imrange""=""currentIM"",))""dateRange""")

        For J = 2 To Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1

             If currentIM = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(IM, 1).Value And CDate(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(J, 5).Value) < MaxDateCurrentIM Then
                Rows(J).EntireRow.Delete
             End If

        Next J
    Next IM

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any ideias would be very much appreciated, the line of code not working is:

```
MaxDateCurrentIM = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(""imrange""=""currentIM"",))""dateRange""")
```

Comment: This can be done in 3 steps without VBA. If you are interested let me know. The same 3 steps can be written in code and it will probably work more efficiently and faster than what you have here. Again, if you are interested, I can explain in an answer.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for your comment, I believe that all examples are useful for the solving of this situation, if you could provide an answer it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this? Your formula syntax was off I think. (Also why set currentIM twice?) Plus, when deleting rows you need to go backwards.

```
Public Sub sbMaxDateByIM()

Dim max As Date
Dim currentIM As String
Dim MaxDateCurrentIM As Date
Dim dateRange As Range
Dim imrange As Range

With Sheets("sheet1")
    Set dateRange = .Range(.Range("E2"), .Range("E2").End(xlDown))
    Set imrange = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Sheets("UniqueIMS").Activate

For IM = 1 To Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    currentIM = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(IM, 1).Value
    MaxDateCurrentIM = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(" & imrange.Address & "=""" & currentIM & """," & dateRange.Address & "))")
    For J = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count + 1 To 2 Step -1
        If currentIM = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(IM, 1).Value And CDate(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(J, 5).Value) < MaxDateCurrentIM Then
            Rows(J).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next J
Next IM

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you support. 
I only have one extra question.
The variable "MaxDateCurrentIM" is currently as type Date, and that throws an error of Type Mismatch. 
The same thing happens if it's define as string, and if I define it as range it gives a error of "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Any ideias why?

Comment: When it errors, what is the value of MaxDateCurrentIM?

Comment: It errors exactly when trying to set the value in MaxDateCurrentIM:
MaxDateCurrentIM = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(" & imrange.Address & "=" & currentIM & "," & dateRange.Address & "))")

Comment: OK, but what do you think the value should be - have you checked? Perhaps there is an error value?

Comment: In this case for IM IM1131366 the value should be 12-09-2017  08:21:02 and if I apply the formula in one cell in the sheet that is the value it returns.

Comment: Try putting this "=MAX(IF(" & imrange.Address & "=" & currentIM & "," & dateRange.Address & "))" in a message box or the immediate window and check the resultant string is as you expect.

Comment: Well in the immediate window it returns a compile error expected expression. However I've put a message box in the code and the return is:
"Evaluate(=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$5897=IM1131366;$E$2:$E$5896))"
Witch is wrong it shoul be "IM1131366" and not IM1131366 without the "" so I modify the code to: =MAX(IF(" & imRange.Address & "=""" & currentIM & """;" & dateRange.Address & ")). And if I copy the msgbox result to the cell works fine. But in VBA it still gives the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155437/discussion-between-nelsonferro-and-sjr).

Comment: `MaxDateCurrentIM = Evaluate("=MAX(IF(" & imrange.Address & "=""" & currentIM & """," & dateRange.Address & "))")` should do it (amended above).

Comment: Even this didn't solve the problem 100% it got me in the right direction. Thank you SJR

Comment: That's funny, it worked for me. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate is used to run Excel functions - but Excel has no idea what imrange and currentim are, they only exist inside the vba routine. You either need to rewrite your maxif in terms excel understands, or use vba code to do the same job as maxif